# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]) Error in data state attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic-typing

I cannot understand, why do I keep getting "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." error.

```
export async function LobbyPage(props) {
let fetched;
const [data, setState] = useState(null);
axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api_shop/")
.then(res => {
    fetched = res.data;
    setState(fetched);
})
return ( 
    <>
    <CatNav />
    <main>
        {data.map((current) => (
            <div className="card">
                <img src={current.photo} alt="Nothing"/>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title">{current.name}</h5>
                    <p className="card-text">
                        {current.desc}
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </main>
    </>
)}
```

It must fetch json data from my DRF backend and just render it via data.map state attribute. Can somebody help with it?

EDIT:
Data is being fetched as well, just something wrong with state and map()

Comment: have you tried `await axios.get`

Comment: @Portal, didn't helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This component isn't necessarily producing the error.  But the component that *uses* it is.  That's because this component doesn't return JSX, it returns a `Promise`:

```
export async function LobbyPage(props) {
```

`async` functions always return a `Promise`.  The component shouldn't be `async`:

```
export function LobbyPage(props) {
```

---

**Aside from that...** Don't make AJAX calls directly in the component's rendering.  That will invoke the AJAX operation every time it renders.  And if the operation updates state, that will trigger a re-render and an infinite render loop.

You can use `useEffect` with an empty dependency array to invoke the AJAX operation once when the component first loads:

```
const [data, setState] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api_shop/")
  .then(res => {
    setState(fetched);
  });
}, []);
```

You also don't need the `fetched` variable, it's not doing anything meaningful.

Additionally, if you're mapping over `data` in the rendering then don't initialize it to `null`, since you can't call `.map()` on `null`.  Initialize it to an empty array:

```
const [data, setState] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your function is `async`, the whole function will now return a `Promise`. All you have to do is to use the `await` keyword to "wait" for the promise to get resolved, and then return the response. So the modified function would be:

```js
export async function LobbyPage(props) {
  let fetched;
  const [data, setState] = useState(null);
  const res = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api_shop/");
  fetched = res.data;
  setState(fetched);
  return ( 
    <>
      <CatNav />
      <main>
        {fetched.map((current) => (
          <div className="card">
            <img src={current.photo} alt="Nothing"/>
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{current.name}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">
                {current.desc}
              </p>
              <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```